# Filter User Reputation Leagues to only those with similar skill sets

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, reputation, stack-exchange

It's probably a bit of an odd request, but is it possible (or would it be possible) to have the ability to filter or group the *User Reputation Leagues* to those with similar skill sets based on the viewing user's Tags? I'm guessing I could rough up a OData client application to do this but I'd imagine other users would benefit from seeing where they stand in comparison to their SO (or other SE site) peers as well.

For clarification: I'm an active user of SO and I take pride in my current overall standing on SO. I commonly interact with the same users answering the same questions or answering the questions of the same users. It would be nice if there was a way to see at a given moment how my rep stacks up to those that I interact with regularly (even though it'd likely be discouraging). This could serve as a vehicle to drive further competition between users within the same bracket, as well as, serving as a learning tool for users that benefit from reading other user's answers.

Perhaps I'm the only one that sees value in having this, and if so then it's not a big deal (I can figure it out on my own) but it seems like something others could benefit from as well.

Comment: I think this is a good idea; I also think it would be relatively easy to implement (being a couple of SQL clauses give or take, and an additional bit of UI).

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I'm glad someone else see's value in it. My experience with meta is full of disappointment and negativity (mostly because I suggest ideas before thinking through them all of the way). It's encouraging that someone actually likes one of my ideas. :)

Comment: I like this idea too, and I'm one of those disappointingly negative people you talk about! :-)

Comment: @RobertHarvey - this would be *sooooo* non-trivial on the backend :)

Comment: @NickCraver: I stand corrected.

Comment: @NickCraver - Am I right in assuming that means this won't make it to the work queue? If so that is fine, but I'd like an _official_ response on it to be able to mark it as answered.

Comment: @M.Babcock - It's not my queue, that's an Emmett question...but no I can't see this happening, it'd be an insane complication over current behavior (currently, we can literally suck everything up to Stack Exchange for an interval in a single query with the new reputation stuff).

Answer (score 3):

You can *sort of* do this by looking at the "top users" for a particular tag (on the pop-out when you mouse over a tag). It will certainly show you how far from the top group you are. It would be good to see that list with a bit more detail on it though - but I imagine you could only ever do it for one tag at once.